# Is it frequent to use two Ethernet cables for one phone line?

Tags: installation, noise, telephone

I'm experiencing some noise on my phone when it is connected in the wall.  There's no noise when connected right in the modem.  So I decided to check things out and I noticed something that seems odd to me.  My telephone jack uses 2, yes two, Ethernet Cat 5 cables.

[image: Telephone Plug]
<sub>(source: [max-worlds.net](http://www.max-worlds.net/diy/telephone-plug.jpg))</sub>

As you can see, both blue wires are connected to red wire on the telephone jack and both white/blue wires are connected to the green wire.  It seems like an odd setup to me.  This is a new house.  On a side note, I'm thinking they could have done that to allow an Ethernet network, but we already have a Cat 6 network going on...

So I'm wondering if this is a frequent practice, a recommended approach or a bad job.

Comment: ANSI TIA/EIA-568 Category 5 Telecommunications Cable. Developed for phone/data communications and adopted as the transmission medium of choice for UTP Ethernet as it carried a signal better than Category 4. What you're seeing is not two phone cables, but a single one stripped out so one twisted pair can be used in a daisy-chain loop. Common practice.

Comment: Cat 5/6/etc are originally intended as generic cables. Ethernet just happened to use them. Using them for other purposes than Ethernet is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably you have two or more phone jacks daisy-chained together.  One cable goes to wherever the phone line enters the house and the other runs to another phone jack somewhere else in the house.

This is a common practice. I did some pricing online, and it seems that Cat 5e is comparable in price to 4-conductor phone cable, so the builders may simply have used it because they had it to hand.

Comment: You beat me to this answer. It should be noted that this was common practice for wiring phone lines in the past.

Comment: It still is pretty common.  There is no need for analog phone lines to be run in a home-run config, it is cheaper to daisy chain since you use less cable.... and most builders are cheap!

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.  I dug up a photo of my house under construction and there's indeed a cable going to my basement and one going to my room upstairs.  I will leave that as is.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Steven Hey, so I am trying to add an RJ45 port to the wall plate that was previously RJ11 (daisy-chained). How do you punch down multiple wires if you are using a modern keystone port that doesn't have screws?